# Primefaces wizard event after onFlowProcess / onnext

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using primefaces (6.0) wizard and would like to invoke a javascript code once tabs are displayed.

```
<p:wizard flowListener="#{bb.onFlowProcess}" onnext="PF('waitDlg').show()"> ...
```

What I need is something like `oncomplete="PF('waitDlg').hide()"`

I'm able to invoke it at `bb.onFlowProcess` end, however, when there is a validation error, `bb.onFlowProcess` isn't invoked and the dialog won't hide.

Is there a solution or workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by doing the following (omitted some code for clarity):

> Removed nav bar

```
<p:wizard flowListener="#{bb.onFlowProcess}" widgetVar="wizard" onnext="PF('waitDlg').show()" showNavBar="false>
```

> Added command buttons for navigation

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="nextBtn" value="Next" onstart="PF('wizard').next();" oncomplete="hideOnValidationFail(args, 'waitDlg')"/>
```

> Kept code to execute js at `onFlowProcess` end

```
 try {
     // code
 } finally {
     executeJavaScript("PF('waitDlg').hide()");
 }
```

> In case one wants to show / hide nav buttons, I achieved it by using a little bit of jquery

```
 <p:tab id="tab1" title="Tab 1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".backBtn").hide();
            $(".nextBtn").show();
            $(".finishBtn").hide();
        });
    </script>
    // tab code
</p:tab>

<p:tab id="tab2" title="Tab 2">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".backBtn").show();
            $(".nextBtn").show();
            $(".finishBtn").hide();
        });
    </script>
    // tab code
</p:tab>
```